# C# Random is generate same value in the foreach

Tags: c#

I want to get random number in per repeat of `foreach` loop

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int s = r.Next(0, 5);                                             
            <span>@(s)</span>                   
        }
```

But I get same value instead of random value.

Comment: Move this `Random r = new Random();` outside of the `foreach` loop.

Comment: The instances of the `Random` class are creating too close in time. So they will all be seeded with the same random sequence.

Comment: Moreover, @S.Akbari - The Random instances are regularly generated with the same seed - due to being created too close in time

Comment: insert a little delay before `Random r = new Random()`, about 20milliseconds, then values will be different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Random r = new Random();

@foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            int s = r.Next(0, 5);                                             
            <span>@(s)</span>                   
        }
```

Comment: It will not help a lot...most of them will be the same